# how to consume asp.net web service in android application

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I have already created asp.net 3.0 web service. I tested it in sample application and it worked. It gives xml output.
problrm id how to consume webservice in android application and sent parameters to the web server.

Comment: Did you try anything, for example, search in Google? keyword : `.net web service android`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ksoap;

```
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
        pi.setName("Category");
        pi.setValue(C);
        pi.setType(C.getClass());
        Request.addProperty(pi);
```

Regarding the return type, if your web method returns a complex object (such as ours), you need to tell KSOAP how to handle the response. That is done with the following code:

```
envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Category",new Category().getClass());


androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
            C.CategoryId =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
            C.Name =  response.getProperty(1).toString();
            C.Description = (String) response.getProperty(2).toString();
```